# Unable to navigate to the url which has value at the end

Tags: testcafe

I am seeing an issue while i am trying to navigate to the url at the end of the url it has some value which is it not being loaded, can you help me on this.
https://workspaces-uat.veteransunited.com/submit-to-uw/ba83b27f-6f7d-4230-93f9-0cd35977b7b7

Comment: We are the TestCafe team, and we would like to help you resolve the issue. However, your current description is not sufficient to determine its cause.



As I can see, you also created the following GitHub issue: [#6957](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6957). Could you please add another comment containing a minimal example and detailed steps to reproduce the issue?



Please use the following template to share detailed information: [Template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml)

Comment: Hi Alex, I am seeing the below issue in the console AuthSdk PKCE error while trying navigate to The URL, i am running this on chrome 92 and windows 10, testCafe version 1.18.5

Comment: I see that you have an outdated browser version. Please update it.

If this doesn't help, please, create a new issue according to [this template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml).